# How to deploy SQL Server changes in desktop based application

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms, deployment

**Environments**

- SQL Server 2008 R2
- Windows Application in C#

**Scenario**

- I have the desktop application which uses SQL Server. The application deployment builds consist of two scripts #1 Create and #2 Update scripts for deploying the database changes. If creating a new database, it will use #1 script.  If updating an existing database, it will use #2 script.  There is never a need to run both.
- The #2 script – is tied to the Version of the Application Code.
- This perfectly fine when the individual user is using a local SQL server.

**Problem**

- We have a client who is using a Central SQL Server where the database is created and individual users connect to same by the desktop application.
- Let us say the client is running Application build 02.12.15.140 and the expected database version number is 1.2.45. This week we released to them a new build 02.12.16.310, and in this version, the database version number is now 1.2.51.  If a user installs build 140, they will be prompted to update the database with the new #2.sql script, which will change the database version number to 1.2.51.  If another user tries to run build 140, they will be unable to connect to the database since application build 140 expects database version 1.2.45 but the database will have been updated to version 1.2.51, due to a central server. Because of this, all users must be on the same client build in order to use the database.

Our challenge is that sometimes to implement new feature or defect, we need to change the database, anywhere from a table design change to a stored procedure change.  So new client software versions require an update to the database.  We want to make sure that the client software is using the correct database design, so we’ve tied the client software to a database version number.  This allows us to ensure that the database design matches what we expect.  But it also creates the inconvenience of forcing all users of a database to update the client software at the same time.

Is there is any solution for deploying database changes in such an environment?

Comment: it might not be the best solution but can you try to have different versions of databases running on the centralized system (for a limited period of time) and whenever there is an update just add the new database and refer the new database to the latest updated application. So the older database related clients will still have access to their data (will not be forced at that time) and whenever they do the next login check for the update just give them a prompt that you have an update available and the current version will be become depricated after xxxxx day(s).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.! If we create a database every time then How will we manage the existing data present the Old database? Right?

Comment: I assumed that database updates are not something that one will do every day and they might be done once or twice a month (excluding minor updates not major updates which may require the complete application to be updated as well). And if you take a look at the mobile application world you will see that whenever there is a new update available the user will be notified but will not be forced until unless it's a major release.  And as for managing the old database, you can replace it with the new one once the deadline is reached by simply checking the deadline with a scheduler or a service.

Comment: Where as the updates are mostly an extension to the current database and not a replacement. But if they are a replacement that means it is more like an Major release(or bug fixes) which require the user to update both applicaiton and database(whichever one is required).